# FB.api name undefined

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I'm working on a new Facebook App for my website using Facebook Connect. I'm using the JS SDK and I try to display the name of the user. Here is my code :

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'myappid', // App ID
      oauth      : 'true',
      channelUrl : '//mychannelfile', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
                // do something with response

            });

    var connecter=false;

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                connecter=true;
                FB.api('/me', function(user) {
                console.log(user.name);
                });
            }
        else connecter=false;
        });
  };
```

If I check the console the result of user.name is undefined when the user is connected. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: have you tried checking console.log(response) object and console.log( user) objects ?

Comment: I don't understand why but when I add console.log(user) before console.log(user.name) it works...

Comment: which means you do see a name attribute in your user object in console ?

Comment: Yes but if I remove console.log(user) it doesn't work. It works if I'm doing an operation with the variable user. It's fine if it works like that but maybe someone can explain why. Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, please check this 
http://www.fbrell.com/saved/9afe7dbf1b4ff2dfdcb87e3ca4536225

Comment: Yes that's what I thought, do you think a conflict is possible with other scripts ? (my webpage is using jwplayer javascript api)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10294/discussion-between-dhiraj-bodicherla-and-kevin-pfefer)

Answer (score 0):

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// init the FB JS SDK
FB.init({
  appId      : '176854392480453',                        
  status     : true,                                 
  xfbml      : true                                 
});

// Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
alert("connected");
connecter=true;
FB.api('/me', function(user) {
alert(user.name);
alert(user.first_name);
alert(user.last_name);
alert(user.email);
});

  } 
 });
```